# Invoke GCF from browser with rate limit/max quota

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I'm building a simple contact form (email + body + submit button) which should send an email to a given address.

I don't want to maintain a server for such purpose and a GCF seemed to fit the usecase. On submit, it would send an email after validating recaptcha.

What I'm concerned though is that I can't seem to find a way to rate limit (or better, set a maximum quota per month) for the Cloud Function.
I checked Cloud Endpoints, but they don't integrate with GCF.

Ideally, I'd like to say: my GCF can't be called more than x times per month.
This would protect me from malicious attackers (it already happened to someone else).

How can I set a nax quota/rate limit my GCF? Is it possible?